# Save XML without formatting

Tags: asp.net-core

I need to generate the xml, but without jumping line, the way I generate it is all indented, how do I save without jumping the line?

```
 document.LoadXml(soapEnvelope);
    document.Save(@"E:\nota.xml");
```

I tried this code below:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("arquivo.xml");
document.Save("arquivo2.xml", SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

However, the SaveOptions option does not appear, I use ASP.NET CORE.

This way the data goes like this below:

```
    <Rps>
      <IdentificacaoRps>
         <Numero>1</Numero>
          <Serie>999</Serie>
          <Tipo>1</Tipo>
      </IdentificacaoRps>
     <DataEmissao>2018-11-27</DataEmissao>
    <Status>1</Status>
  </Rps>
```

And I need them to leave like this.

```
 <Rps><IdentificacaoRps><Numero>1</Numero><Serie>999</Serie><Tipo>1</Tipo</IdentificacaoRps><DataEmissao>2018-11-27</DataEmissao<Status>1</Status></Rps>
```

How to solve this problem, is there any way?

Comment: What version of .net core are you on and what is the error you see? This code compiles in .net core >= 2.0.

Comment: @Neil I use version 2.1, when I include System.Xml.Linq, it returns error in Save which does not take two arguments.

Comment: I just tried your code with `.NET Core 2.0.0`/ `.NET Core 2.1.500`, both run flawlessly. Are you inspecting the xml content in browser or with a plain text editor?

Comment: @itminus It runs without fail, but it needs to be all in the same line, as in the example above, it does not return any type of error.

Comment: @marianac_costa, you asked basically the same question today: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53518785/8133067. Don't do that, many alike questions are no good to Stack Overflow. And here you say that Adam Vincent's answer solved your problem, but on the other question it seems that it doesn't. Also, my answer to the other question was almost the same as Ratan's answer here, and you accepted mine. Did it really work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To efficiently remove the white-space, here I'm creating a new `XmlDocument` with `PreserveWhiteSpace = false`.  Once you load the document from the file, you can access the white space free XML from `doc.InnerXml`, and then you can use that for whatever purpose, but here I'm sticking with the question and writing it to a file, and properly disposing the writer.

```
using (var writer = System.IO.File.CreateText("C:\\b.xml"))
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument {PreserveWhitespace = false};
    doc.Load("C:\\a.xml");
    writer.WriteLine(doc.InnerXml);
    writer.Flush();
}
```

Comment: It did not work, it still jumps the lines, I need everything in one line, for example: <tag><tag1>example</tag1></tag>

Comment: Ah. I understand. Add that to your post.  Some might not understand "jumping the line", it's better understood as "new line"

Answer (score 0):

Try if this helps-

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("arquivo.xml");

XmlWriterSettings xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
xmlSettings.Indent = false;
xmlSettings.NewLineChars = String.Empty;
using (XmlWriter xwWriter = XmlWriter.Create(@"c:\YourFileName.xml", xmlSettings))
document.Save(xwWriter);
```

Comment: It did not work for me, it continues to generate in each line.

Comment: It continues one on each line in the same way, I need everything on a single line, the same problem happens.